# solve surface integral of a scalar function using divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Use the Divergence Theorem to evaluate:

$$\iint_S (2x+2y+z^2) dS$$

where $S$ is the sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$$

Most of the examples on the book that needs to be solved using divergence theorem are given in the form of a vector field. This one, however, is a scalar function. We know that if we want to use divergence theorem we need a vector field, take the divergence, and then integrate over the volume. I think this one need to somehow convert the scalar function $$2x+2y+z^2$$ into a vector field and then use divergence theorem. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What have you done on this?  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: Most of the examples on the book that needs to be solved using divergence theorem are given in the form of a vector field. This one, however, is a scalar function. We know that if we want to use divergence theorem we need a vector field, take the divergence, and then integrate over the volume. I think this one need to somehow convert the scalar function 2x+2y+z^2 into a vector field and then use divergence theorem. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: OK, you're right. So what is the unit normal vector $\vec n$ at $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere? Can you invent a vector field $\vec F$ so that $\vec F\cdot\vec n = 2x+2y+z^2$?

Comment: Can unit normal vector be <x,y,z> and then the vector field is <2,2,z>?

Comment: @StacyAceIt Put your long comment in the body of your question before it gets closed for lack of context.

Comment: Yes. Excellent. Now finish the problem (and put that as an edit for your question, too). :P

Answer (score 2):

Note that

- $\vec n=(x,y,z)$
- $\vec F \cdot \vec n=2x+2y+z^2 \implies \vec F=(2,2,z)$

thus

- $\nabla \cdot \vec F=1$

and then

$$\iint_S (2x+2y+z^2) dS=\iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n\, dS=\iiint_V 1\cdot dV
$$

Comment: I think you are right! Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye